# Python 3 Memory Consumption Spikes while processing more than 10K Files

Tags: text

Greeting

I am writing a python 3 code that process 28K JSON text files. each file is 3K bytes and being opened processed (read line by line) and then CLOSED successfully.
The code runs fine with memory consumption less than 0.5 GB shown by the Windows task manager.

All of a sudden, the memory consumption spikes substantially and start growing  until the code consumes 31 GB of my 32 GB physical memory, this happens when the code finished processing 10K out of 28K physical file on my HD.

It is quite puzzling and I am wondering what is the explanation for this sudden memory consumption, why the memory spike taking place above 10K files.

Any feedback is highly appreciated ..

Comment: Code sample would be very helpful , and by physical memory do you mean RAM??